# Adding a Custom Widget to Qt Designer

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I've got the following custom widget:

```
class QDESIGNER_WIDGET_EXPORT MySpecialButton : public QAbstractButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...etc...
};
```

Qt Designer recognizes this widget, and I can place it onto my form without a problem.  However, when looking in the property editor, only the QObject and QWidget properties are visible.  How do I get Qt Designer to recognize that this is also a QAbstractButton object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you have the `Q_OBJECT` macro in your class definition.  Also, make sure the file was properly `moc`ed.  If neither of those help, you might investigate how `QPushButton` and `QToolButton` are declared to see if that gives you any hints.

Finally, if you need a chainsaw approach rather than a scalpel, you could define the properties you want to set in your class, giving the `QAbstractButton` functions as the ones to  call for the properties.  Look into the [`Q_PROPERTY`](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.5/qobject.html#Q_PROPERTY) macro.

Comment: Thanks, but I've got the Q_OBJECT macro in there (edited my question for clarity).  I was getting compiler errors until I fixed that.

I've looked at QPushButton, and I didn't see anything special about it.  I'm going to leave this question up for awhile, and if I never get a solution, I guess I'll go the chainsaw route.

Comment: Incidentally, I went the chainsaw route. I never saw a difference between my custom class and `QPushButton`.